# How to use the final value of two different function to get another value in python?

Tags: python

I want to develop an electric calculator which :

1. Converts money into units(KWh).
2. It also takes user input to determine how many electric component he/she uses in home in order to determine average electricity consumption per day.
3. After having those in inputs and calculation it will also show how many day he/she can have against the money he/she recharged(Ex: for 10$ he can have 100 Kwh, if average use per day is 10 KWh how many day he can have? [day=100kwh/10kwh=10 days]

I have solved 1 and 2 problem using two function, now i want to use the final value of those two function to get the day. i was trying to divide the final of those function. is it possible to divide the value of those function?

## 1. this function converts money into units in KWh

```
def money_to_unit():

    recharge=int(input("Enter yor recharge amount : "))

    amount=recharge-(recharge*(5/100)) # after deducting 5% vat

    unit=0

    if amount<=300:   #300 is max value for using 75 Kwh
        unit=amount/4  # 4 is the slab rate for 0-75 Kwh

    elif amount<=981.25:    #981.25 is max value for using 200 Kwh
        unit=75+((amount-300)/5.45) #5.45 is the slab rate for 76-200  Kwh 

    elif amount<=1551.25:    #1551.25 is max value for using 300 Kwh
        unit=75+125+((amount-681.25)/5.7) #5.7 is the slab rate for 201-300 Kwh
    elif amount<=2153.25:
        unit=75+125+100+((amount-1551.25)/6.02)
    elif amount<=4013.25:
        unit=75+125+100+100+((amount-2153.25)/9.30)
    else:
        unit=75+125+100+100+200+((amount-4013.25)/10.7)

    print("Useable amount is :"+ " "+str(round(amount,2))+" "+"Taka")
    print("Useable unit is: "+" "+str(round(unit,2))+" "+"Kwh")

money_to_unit()
```

## 2. to determine the average use per day in KWh

```
def comp():

    light=int(input("Enter the number of light :"))

    watt=int(input("Enter the watt : "))

    hour=int(input("Enter the agerage use of light in hour per day : "))

    consumption=(light*watt*hour)/1000

    print("you total consumption is"+ " " + str(consumption)+ " " + "Kwh per day")

comp()
```

## 3. divided `money_to_unit()` by `comp()`. how to do it?

(1).for 500 taka, usable amount is 475 taka, usable unit is 107.11 Kwh

(2).for 5 light of 20 w per hour using 6 hour a day, average use is 0.6 Kwh per day.

(3). day = 107.11 Kwh/0.6 Kwh = 178.5 day

Comment: pro tip: use `return`

Comment: `return` the values you need to divide from both functions

Comment: @Mus please accept the answer that helped you solve your problem by clicking on the tick sign beside it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both of your function should return the calculated value that you want to use for further calculations (instead of just printing it).

```
def money_to_unit():
    /* function definition */
    return round(amount,2), round(amount,2)
```

and

```
def comp():
    /* function definition */
    return consumption
```

Then you can simply call the functions like this:

```
x, y = money_to_unit()
z =  comp()
```

and finally you can perform any extra calculation you want with x,y,z like:

```
result = x/z 
/* or */
result2 = y/z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def money_to_unit():

# all your previous code

return round(unit,2)

def comp():

# all your previous code

return consumption
```

and perhaps:

```
money_unit = money_to_unit()
consumption = comp()

day = money_unit / consumption
print(round(day,1), "{}".format("day"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
178.5 day
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`. Give functions specific tasks to do, not only wrapping around some scripts.

1.Define two functions for first step:

```
def recharge_to_amount(recharge, vat):
     return recharge * (1 - vat)
```

and

```
def amount_to_kwh(amount):
    if amount <= 300:
        return amount / 4
    elif amount <= 981.25:
        return 75 + ((amount - 300) / 5.45)
    elif amount <= 1551.25:
        return 75 + 125 + ((amount - 681.25) / 5.7)
    elif amount <= 2153.25:
        return 75 + 125 + 100 + ((amount - 1551.25) / 6.02)
    elif amount <= 4013.25:
        return 75 + 125 + 100 + 100 + ((amount - 2153.25) / 9.30)
    else:
        return 75 + 125 + 100 + 100 + 200 + ((amount - 4013.25) / 10.7)
```

2.Define another function for second step:

```
def consumption(light, watt, hour):
    return light * watt * hour / 1000
```

3.Define last function:

```
def days(watt, cons):
    return watt / cons
```

And perform your calculation:

```
amount = recharge_to_amount(500)
kwh = amount_to_kwh(amount)
consumption = consumption(5, 20, 6)

days = days(kwh, consumption)
```